# ranges and temporary initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to pass what I think is a prvalue into a range adapter closure object. It won't compile unless I bind a name to the initializer list and make it an lvalue. What is happening here?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  //why does this compile?
  auto init_list = {1,2,4};
  auto v = init_list | views::drop(1);
  
  //but not this?
  // auto v2 = initializer_list<int>{1,2,4} | views::drop(1);

  //or this?
  //auto v3 = views::all(initializer_list<int>{1,2,4}) | views::drop(1);
}
```

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102)

Comment: Initializer lists are used for *initializing* objects. You shouldn't try to treat them as a cheap-and-dirty way to create a sequence of values to manipulate. They do not work well for this purpose.

Comment: Change `initializer_list` to `std::array` and it works https://godbolt.org/z/rPqs5xhxT although sadly not for range-v3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `r | views::drop(1)` to create a new `view`, range adaptors will automatically convert `r` into a `view` for you. This requires that the type of `r` must model [`viewable_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/viewable_range):

```
template<class T>
  concept viewable_­range =
    range<T> &&
    ((view<remove_cvref_t<T>> && constructible_­from<remove_cvref_t<T>, T>) ||
     (!view<remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
      (is_lvalue_reference_v<T> || (movable<remove_reference_t<T>> && !is-initializer-list<T>))));
```

Note the last requirement:

```
(is_lvalue_reference_v<T> || (movable<remove_reference_t<T>> && !is-initializer-list<T>))));
```

Since the type of `r` doesn't model a `view`, which in your case is `initializer_list`, it needs to be an *lvalue*, allowing us to freely take its address to construct a [`ref_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ref_view) without worrying about dangling.

Or, we need it to be `movable`, which allows us to transfer its ownership to [`owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view), which means the following is well-formed:

```
auto r = std::vector{42} | views::drop(1)
```

But in this case, we also need it not to be a specialization of `initializer_list`, because we can't transfer ownership of it, `initializer_list` always copy. That's why your example fails.

Answer (score 1):

The situation as of C++23 seems to be ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6Kd7rYaTj)): `initializer_list` is a contiguous range, but not a view and not a borrowed range. This is counterintuitive, since in fact

- `initializer_list` is *exactly* a non-owning view over a range that lives somewhere else; copying an `initializer_list` is always cheap and always "shallow not deep." So *a priori* you'd think it's a `view`.
- `initializer_list`'s internal state is *exactly* a pointer and a length and nothing else; it can safely be "deboned" into a pair of pointers. So *a priori* you'd think it's a "borrowed range."

My hypothesis is that the current wording makes sense primarily because `initializer_list` is not actually a value type; it's more of a [syntactic tag, like `std::nullptr_t` or `std::reference_wrapper`](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/03/07/monostate-vs-nullopt/). We rarely pass around *values* of type `initializer_list`. Instead, they pop into existence to represent a syntactic feature of the call-site. The actual *type itself* doesn't behave like a well-behaved C++20 Ranges range (if such a thing can be said to exist at all).

```
template<class R>
auto debone(R rg) {
    static_assert(std::borrowed_range<R>);
    return std::ranges::subrange(rg.begin(), rg.end());
}

auto x = debone<std::initializer_list<int>>({1,2,3,4});
  // fails the static_assert -- good!
```

If this code didn't fail to compile, then the returned `x` would contain a pair of iterators into a temporary array (the backing array of the `initializer_list`) which has already been destroyed.
Other "parameter-only types" must deal with the same tradeoff. They generally *do* advertise borrowed-range-ness, and justify themselves by being a teeny tiny bit harder to construct accidentally from a temporary:

```
auto x = debone<std::string_view>("hello world");
  // compiles quietly, but also happens to work

auto x = debone<std::string_view>("hello world"s);
  // compiles quietly, and has UB: x.begin() dangles

auto x = debone<std::span<const int>>({{1,2,3}});
  // compiles quietly, and has UB, but will likely work "in practice" (*)

auto x = debone<std::span<const int>>(std::vector{1,2,3}});
  // compiles quietly, and has UB: x.begin() dangles
```

(* — See [P2752 "Static storage for braced initializers"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2752r3.html), adopted as a DR in 2023, for why this will likely appear to work in practice. But it's still accessing the backing array outside of its actual lifetime.)

I hypothesize that `span` and `string_view` "correctly" advertise themselves as borrowed views because they expect to sometimes be used as value types rather than "parameter-only types" (this is also why they provide `operator=` and `swap`, for example). But `initializer_list` is pretty much a "pure" parameter-only type — it has even been [seriously proposed](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2432) to eliminate its `operator=`. `initializer_list` doesn't expect ever to be passed to a Ranges algorithm on purpose. So it doesn't bother to advertise itself as a borrowed range or a view.