# How can std::ranges work with initializer_list?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, stdinitializerlist

I wonder if the `std::ranges::*` algorithms should be working with `std::initializer_list`.
For example, line `(B)` in the following snippet compiles while line `(A)` does not, when compiling with x64 MSVC v19.latest and option `/std:c++latest` [(godbolt.org/z/5oTEz1q5P)](https://godbolt.org/z/5oTEz1q5P).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
static_assert(std::ranges::is_sorted({ ONE, TWO }));  // (A)
static_assert(std::ranges::is_sorted(std::array { ONE, TWO }));  // (B)
int main() {}
```

The underlying temporary array that is allocated for the initializer_list should live until the call to `is_sorted()` in line `(A)` has returned.

According to the error message, `std::initializer_list` cannot be casted to a `std::ranges::forward_range`:
*algorithm(10432): 'bool std::ranges::_Is_sorted_fn::operator ()(_Rng &&,_Pr,_Pj) const': could not deduce template argument for '_Rng'*.

Is this the same reason as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264027/ranges-and-temporary-initializer-lists)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code `std::ranges::is_sorted({ ONE, TWO })`, is that it cannot deduce the type of `{ ONE, TWO }` within a template parameter.

To actually do this, you must either manually create a `initializer_list` first:

```cpp
std::ranges::is_sorted(std::initializer_list{ ONE, TWO })
```

Or the function itself must not deduce the type of this parameter.

---

Sidenote, this is one place where the behavior of `auto` differ from template deduction.

`auto` is specifically given the ability to deduce `il` within this syntax:

```cpp
auto il = {a, b, c};
```

No other usually equivalent syntaxes can deduce this as `initializer_list`, including `auto il{a, b, c}`, `template_func({a, b, c})`, and etc..